# How MVC client get tokens from IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm studying IdentityServer4 and creating the MVC client as this guide
https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_interactive_aspnetcore.html

what part I don't understand is that how Ids4 send id_token and access_token to mvc client after logged in Ids4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the flow, but if you use the authorization code flow, then an authorization code is returned to the client after the user authenticates, and using this code, it can then send it back to IdentityServer to retrieve the actual tokens. This is done directly between the client and IdentityServer and this you don't see in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I am setting up to use AuthenticationCode flow. I see that the Ids4 callback to MVC client by posting (code, scope, state, session_state) to /signin-oidc route after authenticated. Can you explain more about this one, how it work?
[This is done directly between the client and IdentityServer and this you don't see in the browser.] Thanks for your time.

Comment: I got it. The connect/token endpoint is called as while posting to /signin-oidc. Thank you so much.